# Assigning an array to different table columns using the has_many through association, Rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

Heres my situation, I have set up two models via the has_many through association as outlined [here in the rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association). To access one from the other will generally be done via an array, however I don't really want an array, I would like 3 separate values.

Example: 
I have two models, Cars and Garages (plus car_garage join). I'd like 3 cars in each garage, i'd also like to assign each of those cars to a corresponding column in my Garage table, 'garage.everyday_car', 'garage.weekly_car' and 'garage.special_car'.

so rather than collecting all 3 values in one collection_select like this

```
= f.collection_select(:car_ids, Car.all, :id, :name), {}, {multiple: true}
```

Is it possible to split the array into three select boxes? Where I can specify the position in the array that the select box value will occupy, such as:

```
# attempt to assign the monthly car as 3rd in the array every time
= f.collection_select(:car_ids[2], Car.all, :id, :name), {}, {multiple: true}
```

and then somehow connect that value to a particular column in my garage table like - garage.monthly_car == car_ids[2]

or is there a way that I'm missing here? Basically I'd like 3 different types of car each assigned to a column in my garage.

Sorry if this is poorly explained, I'm still trying to get it straight in my head, if you think code examples or more information could help just leave a comment thanks. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully understanding what you want, but if you want the relation to be richer you can always extend the join table with a model (I assume you did that as you're using `has_many :through`).

What I'm saying is that you can add a column `:type` and simply use three collection select for each type, that relation being stored in the controller.

You could also create one scope for each type of car in your Garage model, so you can use `Garage.special_car` or whatever you need.

This approach avoids the duplication of data (and all the hassle that comes with it).

If in doubt, comment.

GL & HF.